# Why is this Infinite Looping - Simple Game script in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, infinite

Writing a simple game script to guess the correct number of 42.

I get an infinite loop in the for/else statements. Can someone please tell me why? I am very very new to Bash

Thanks

```
    #!/bin/bash

read -p "Please pick a number between 1 and 100: " x
q=exit
while true 
do
if [ "$x" = "q" ]
    then
        exit
      

fi
#done
if  [ "$x" -gt "42" ]; then 
echo -e "That number is too high!" 
else read -p "try again :" 

fi
if [ "$x" -lt "42" ]; 
then echo -e "That number is too low!" 
else read -p "try again :"
fi
if [ "$x" = "42" ] ; 
then echo -e "You are Correct!!!" 
else read -p "try again :"
fi
done
exit
```

Comment: The only way you exit the loop is if you enter `q`; there's no provision to use `break` or `exit` when `x` equals 42.

Comment: I know 42 is always the answer... but if you want the script to pick a randowm number for you, try `n=$(( (RANDOM % 100) +1 ))`. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line populates `$x`:

```
read -p "Please pick a number between 1 and 100: " x
```

This line populates `$REPLY`:

```
read -p "try again :"
```

Comment: so do I need to add a variable for $reply if so, how do I direct it to begin the script again?

Comment: Add the `x` at the end to populate `$x`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The infinite loop has stopped however it still steps through 3 try again's before the answer is given.  Feels weird to this newby.

Comment: That's because you should use `if ... elif ... elif ... else ... fi` instead of three independent ifs. It's also possible to restructure the script to only have one read, both for the initial guess and any subsequent guesses.